# App closes when emulator is rotated

Tags: android, android-emulator

I have finished my app. I have made two separate XML folders for portrait view and for landscape view. When I try to run my app, in the middle get switch from one view to another view, the app closes any idea why this occurs?

Comment: Any logcat entries to show ?

Comment: Any exceptions or anything on your LogCat ?

Comment: Also, posting the Manifest might be useful

Answer (score 0):

Without any log it is hard to give an asnwer. 
You can give a look here [Recreating an Activity](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/recreating.html) where it says

> Caution: Your activity will be destroyed and recreated each time the user rotates the screen. When the screen changes orientation, the system destroys and recreates the foreground activity because the screen configuration has changed and your activity might need to load alternative resources (such as the layout).

It could be you don't initialize correctly some variables.